# How do I get the length of nested object inside a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects:

```
const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];
```

I would like to write a program that calculates the length of the `data` field for every entry in the array. The expected output should be:

```
6
4
```

Here's what I've tried so far, but can't get it out:

```
const res = mockData.reduce((sum, item) => item.data.length, 0);
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: how you expecting length `5` and `3` ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `6` and `4`? And why not simply use `data.length`?

Comment: `mockData.map(({data}) => data.length)` ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Ooops, sure. Updated the question

Comment: Use map, you don't need reduce here, `mockData.map( item => item.data.length );`

Comment: @CodeManiac Map will return an array, but I need numbers

Comment: @drevival `Map` and `map` are two different thing, you can loop over array to get your numbers

Comment: @Pac0 Yeah, so I thought I need a reduce

Comment: "will return an array, but I need numbers", yes, so an array of numbers is satisfactory, isn't it?

Comment: @Pac0 Yeah, not satisfactory. I need numbers

6
4

Comment: What mythical format are you expecting for the numbers if `[6, 4]` is not satisfactory for you?

Comment: you can't "return 2 numbers". You can _print_ two numbers, you can return _a data structure_ (like an array) that contains the 2 numbers. Your requirement is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the array to get desired.

I think you just need value like `6 4` so use this line.

> `mockData.map(({data}) => data.length).join(' '); // 6 4`

if you want to show count in new line replace `.join(' ');` with `.join('\n');`

```js
const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];

// log it
mockData.forEach((it) => console.log(it.data.length));

// or print it on web page
mockData.forEach((it) => document.write(it.data.length + '\n'));

// So enjoy one number here
mockData.map(({data}) => data.length).join(' ');
```

Comment: I don't need to log this data. I just need a method with will return two numbers, that's why reduce is needed..

Comment: `.map` will return 2 numbers in another array. isn't that enough ?

Comment: @drevival `.reduce` will infact return 1 number, so how is that as per your requirement?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava : *'...will in fact return 1 number'* why? `mockData.reduce((r,{data}) => (r.push(data.length), r), [])`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  I meant in the way that OP is using in his question. Starting with `0` and not `[]`, which is why the general suggestion is to use `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

```
const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [`enter code here`
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];

  var dataLengthArr = function(){
    return mockData.map((obj)=>{
        return obj["data"].length;
    });
  }

  console.log(dataLengthArr());
```